# Does 'the act' refer to 'to be a cheater'?

Tags: usage

Does ***the act*** refer to ***to be a cheater***, not ***cheating*** in this passage? In view of context, I think both ***the act*** and ***the behavior*** refer to ***to be a cheater***, not ***cheating***. But I am not 100% sure.

> Bryan finds that appeal to character are effective for adults as well.
> His team was able to cut cheating in half: instead of “Please don’t
> cheat,” they changed the appeal to “Please don’t be a cheater.” When
> you’re urged not to cheat, you can do it and still see an ethical
> person in the mirror. But when you’re told not to be a cheater, ***the
> act*** casts a shadow; immorality is tied to your identity, making
> ***the behavior*** much less attractive. Cheating is an isolated action that gets evaluated with the logic of consequence: Can I get
> away with it? Being a cheater evokes a sense of self, triggering the
> logic of appropriateness: What kind of person am I, and who do I want
> to be? In light of this evidence, Bryan suggests that we should
> embrace nouns more thoughtfully. “Don’t Drink and Drive” could be
> rephrased as: “Don’t Be a Drunk Driver.” The same thinking can be
> applied to originality. When a child draws a picture, instead of
> calling the artwork creative, we can say “You are creative.”

[Originals: How Non-conformists Change the World](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=rISmCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT193&lpg=PT193&dq=But%20when%20you%E2%80%99re%20told%20not%20to%20be%20a%20cheater,%20the%20act%20casts%20a%20shadow;%20immorality%20is%20tied%20to%20your%20identity,&source=bl&ots=sW0yVSBFDt&sig=ACfU3U2ie0bqWpFkd40T1dcKDyJVPrz5Rg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYkbHat6T6AhWny4sBHYL9CpgQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=But%20when%20you%E2%80%99re%20told%20not%20to%20be%20a%20cheater%2C%20the%20act%20casts%20a%20shadow%3B%20immorality%20is%20tied%20to%20your%20identity%2C&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Cheating is an act. Being a cheat is not an act, so "the act" and "the behavior" refer to *the act of cheating*.

> The act (of cheating) casts a shadow

This is because the act makes you feel bad about yourself if you've been asked not to be a cheater, rather than simply asked not to cheat.